# Sleep detection in android

Tags: android, sleep

I Want to build app which detect the sleep analysis.
After doing some R&D found we can detect using the **Accelerometer Sensor** and **Microphone**

Have no idea how to Achieve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I have done a previous project to detect when the person is sleeping using video streaming and eye ratio on Android so please let me know if you're interested to publish it on GitHub and post the link

Comment: can you please share it.